# How do I define colors for individual bars on my STACKED bar graph according to their values

Tags: matlab, colors, figure

The figure I'll refer to, can be found here: http://oi44.tinypic.com/2utgbo3.jpg

I'm trying to create a plot similar to that shown in Plot 1. Depending on a value shown in Plot 2, the color of the stacked bar (essentially boxes) should change.

After some research, I found the following [Solution on mathworks](http://www.mathworks.ch/support/solutions/en/data/1-1T6UHS/) for individual coloring of bar charts in matlab.

The trouble I'm having now is to adapt the problem to stacked bars. 
To keep it simple, I first tried to just change the code from the mathworks solution for stacked charts:

```
  mydata=rand(2,3);                        % here I added a 2nd row
  bar_h=bar(mydata,'stack');               % here I added 'stack'
  bar_child=get(bar_h,'Children');
  set(bar_child,'CData',mydata);

  mycolor=[0 0 0;0 0 1;1 0 0];
  colormap(mycolor)
  set(bar_child,'CDataMapping','direct');

  for iCount=1:length(mydata)
      if (mydata(iCount)<.2)
          index(iCount)=1;
      elseif(mydata(iCount)>=.6)
          index(iCount)=3;
      else
          index(iCount)=2;
      end
  end

  set(bar_child, 'CData',index);
  colormap(mycolor);
```

The first problem arises at the line:

```
set(bar_child,'CData',mydata);
```

with the following error:

> Error using set   Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Can you please give me some help in adapting this solution for stacked bars?

Regards,

bearli

Comment: You can start by changing line three to `bar_child=cell2mat(get(bar_h,'Children'));`

Comment: Huh? I ran this code without problems (Matlab R2007a)